# SQL Syntax to search multiple tables

Tags: sql

I need to search for a value in 30 different tables that link back to an operator table.

1..* relationship (an operator can be referenced by any of these 30 tables using two columns) **createdby** and **modifiedby**

Currently im running 30 select statement to find any references to these tables i.e.

```
Select * from table.namespc.contnt 
where iCreatedById = 12345
or imodifiedby = 12345
```

then I do an update on any tables where references where found.

```
UPDATE table.namespc.contnt 
SET iCreatedById = 54321, iModifiedById = 54321
where iCreatedById = 12345
or iModifiedById = 12345
```

Is there an easier way to accomplish this process? add the tables to an array? the values to variables and just search and update if found?

Comment: Seems like poor database design. Consider re-modelling it!

Comment: iCreatedById and imodifiedby should probably be stored only ounce in one table only.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temporary table containing the name of your 30 tables that may have a reference to the operator.
Then, by means of a cursor, loop over its elements and compose dynamically the update-query. This query should be run by means of an `execute immediate`.

By the way, the update query should be split into 2 separate queries:

```
UPDATE table.namespc.contnt
   SET iCreatedById = 54321
 WHERE iCreatedById = 12345;
UPDATE table.namespc.contnt
   SET iModifiedById = 54321
 WHERE iModifiedById = 12345;
```

This because you otherwise update both the creator and modifier in case either one is the one you're looking for.